# Generate HTML form and process it in one PERL/CGI file

Tags: forms, perl, cgi

I am trying to create a form with PERL/CGI, and I would like to process the data introduced in that form  within the same CGI file.

here is my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use CGI qw(:standard);

my $cgi = new CGI;

print header, start_html("Shop web"),

  h1({-align=>center, -style=>"color:blue;Font-Size: 35pt;"},'Oferta T-shirt' ), 
  "<p align=\"center\">
  \<img src=\"/img/t-shirts.jpg\" width=\"30%\">
    <\/p>",

    "<br\\>
    <table align = \"center\" border = \"2\" bordercolor=\"green\" >
            <col width=\"120\">
            <col width=\"120\">
            <col width=\"120\"> 
            <tr>
                <th bgcolor=\"lightgray\">Talla</th>
                <th bgcolor=\"lightgray\">Color</th> 
                <th bgcolor=\"lightgray\">Precio</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align=\"center\">S</td>
                <td align=\"center\">Negro</td> 
                <td align = \"center\">8 &euro;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align=\"center\">M</td>
                <td align=\"center\">Blanco</td> 
                <td align=\"center\">9 &euro; </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align=\"center\">L</td>
                <td align=\"center\">Azul</td> 
                <td align= \"center\">11.5 &euro; </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align= \"center\">XL</td>
                <td align= \"center\">Rojo</td> 
                <td align= \"center\">12 &euro; </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align= \"center\">XXL</td>
                <td align= \"center\">Amarillo</td> 
                <td align= \"center\">15.5 &euro; </td>
            </tr>
        </table> ",

        "<br />
        <h2 align=\"center\"><font color = \"blue\"> Compra tu camiseta</font></h2>
        <br>",

        "<center>

            <form action=\"compra.cgi\" method=\"POST\" >
                <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"subject\" value=\"Formulario por email\">
                <table> 

                    <tr><td>Direcci&oacuten de envio</td>
                        <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"nombre\" size=\"35\"></td>
                    </tr> 

                    <tr> 
                        <td>Cantidad</td> 
                        <td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"cantidad\" size=\"6\"></td> 
                    </tr> 

                    <tr> 

                        <td colspan=\"2\" align=\"center\">   
                            <br>
                            <input type=\"submit\" name=\"Enviar\" value=\"Comprar\"  style=\"height: 30px; width: 120px\"> 
                        </td> 
                    </tr> 
                </table> 
            </form> 
        </center>",


end_html();
```

In other words: how can I process the data introduced in the form without creating another CGI file to capture that data.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#CGI.pm-HAS-BEEN-REMOVED-FROM-THE-PERL-CORE

Comment: You might want to find a modern guide to writing webpages. We've had CSS for over two decades now.

Comment: The HTML generation from CGI.pm [has been deprecated recently](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used) and [CGI.pm has been removed from the core](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#CGI.pm-HAS-BEEN-REMOVED-FROM-THE-PERL-CORE). If your environment only supports CGI, you should still use a Template engine like [Text::XSlate](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Xslate) instead of this ugly wall of escaped HTML. [Watch this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKOqtRMT85s) to see what I mean.

Comment: @Quentin it's at least like, 2000, right? We even have refrigerators! :)

Comment: Don't. It's a recipe for spaghetti code and security holes. Instead, have a common library that both programs use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use CGI qw/:standard/;

print header( 'text/plain' );

$cgi = CGI->new();

if ( $cgi->param )
{
    <<< YOU HAVE POST DATA - PROCESS IT >>>
}
else
{
    <<< THERE IS NO POST DATA - PRINT YOUR HTML >>>
}
```

I do that like this ...

Comment: A bit more explanation would greatly improve your answer.

Comment: @Duncan where should I place this code in my code ??

Comment: Hi rainman. Just place your HTML form code inside the "no params" bit, and process the posted data in the other bit. Either you have posted data or you don't, so right at the start of the script you can branch accordingly.

Comment: I've edited the script slightly to make more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be writing a web application in the mid-1990s. This will, at least update you to use Perl practices from the start of this millennium.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI qw[params header];
use Template;

my $tt = Template->new;

if (params) {
  # We have some CGI parameters, extract them, do something
  # useful with them and then display a page thanking the user.

  my $foo = param('foo');
  my $bar = param('bar');

  process_user_input($foo, $bar);

  $tt->process('thankyou.tt', { foo => $foo, bar => $bar })
    or die $tt->error;
} else {
  # No parameters, so let's show the user the input form
  $tt->process('form.tt')
    or die $tt->error;
}
```

Notice that we avoid using the heavily-deprecated HTML generation functions from CGI.pm. Instead we use the [Template Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/release/Template-Toolkit), which allows us to separate our output into template files (here called `form.tt` and `thankyou.tt`).

Notice that there's a certain amount of hand-waving here as I don't know what the names of your parameters are or what you need to do with them.

But this is still old technology. You would be well advised to read [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) and update your technology to something written this millennium.